# Conditional formatting cells to match another cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, background-color, conditional-formatting

im updating this question in hopes of a solution that doesn't require a script. I need cells in a row to turn the same color as B9. B9 could be "Football","Hockey","Basketball" or "Baseball" and each has a specific color. Is there a formula that will see what's entered in column B AND also see that a negative number had been entered and thus turning the same color as the column B cell.

For Example:

In picture below i want D9:O9 to turn the same red as B9 if a negative value has been entered. Or if "Football" is entered in that B9 D9:O9 will automatically switch to green.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to reference color in conditional formatting is not possible. you can either pre-program it manually or use a script which will color your cells based on color

Comment: Thanks! Would it be possible if i changed column B to have a specific word it looked for? For instance, instead of "week 1" i put "Football 1". if it sees that word then i can set it to change to the matching color? if that makes sense

Answer (score 1):

Just use the conditional formatting rule: `is not empty`
as per the image and adjust range and colour to your needs.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that the color in B9 will vary week to to week. Sometimes the row will be red, teal, yellow etc. That's why i need it to be based solely on what color is in column B